# Create view : MySQL Inner join aliases

Tags: mysql, inner-join, alias

I am trying to create a view in MySQL, however, an error occured:
`Duplicate column name 'profil_id'`

This is my request:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS SELECT * FROM `profils` AS `p` 
INNER JOIN `table_A` ON table_A.profil_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN `table_B` ON table_B.profil_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = '1';
```

I know this is because I have to create an alias for profil_id, but I don't know how to figure out that with an `INNER JOIN`...

```
INNER JOIN `table_A` ON table_A.profil_id = p.id AS table_A_profil_id
```

Does not work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT `p`.*, `table_A`.`profil_id` AS table_A_profil_id, `table_B`.`profil_id` AS table_B_profil_id
    FROM `profils` AS `p` 
        INNER JOIN `table_A` ON table_A.profil_id = p.id 
        INNER JOIN `table_B` ON table_B.profil_id = p.id
    WHERE p.id = '1';
```

You can't use `*` in this case because you `INNER JOIN` two tables with the same column name. You need to list the columns for these two tables and set an alias to the duplicate column names.